# Savon : response doesn't shows data but type details of response

Tags: ruby, soap, response, savon

I am using SAVON to invoke soap service from Ruby. Response is a complex type and to_hash is giving following response which does not contain actual data in response.

```
{:get_data_response=>{:record=>{:"@xsi:type"=>"tns:record"}}}
```

response by soap is object and type is described in wsdl as shown below

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:WashOut">
<xsd:complexType name="record">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:int"/>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</schema>
</types>
<message name="get_data">
<part name="value" type="xsd:int"/>
</message>
<message name="get_data_response">
<part name="record" type="tns:record"/>
</message>
```

how to parse response using type definition is WSDL?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9490619/2035262

Comment: issue is response I am getting is as follows, {:get_data_response=>{:record=>{:"@xsi:type"=>"tns:record"}}}